# How to store a variable and use it afterwards in a calculator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, input, calculator

Here's my code:

```
cont = "Y"
greeting = print("Hi, welcome to the calculator. What is your calculation?: ")


num1 = float(input("What is the first number you would like to use? "))
op = input("Select operation: (+, -, /, *, **) ")
num2 = float(input("What is the second number you would like to use? "))

if op == '+':
    x = num1 + num2
    print (x)
elif op == '-':
    x = num1 - num2
    print(x)
elif op == '/':
    x = num1 / num2
    print(x)
elif op == '*':
    x = num1 * num2
    print(x)
elif op == '**':
    x = num1 ** num2
    print(x)
else:
    print("error")
    pass


cont = input("Would you like to use another term? (Y/N): ")

while cont == "Y":
   op1 = input("Select operation: (+, -, /, *, **)")
   num = float(input(("Input the next number: ")))
   if op1 == '+':
        y = x + num
        print (y)
        cont = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ")
   elif op1 == '-':
        z = x - num
        print(z)
        cont = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ")
   elif op1 == '/':
        div = x / num
        print(div)
        cont = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ")
   elif op1 == '*':
        mult = x * num
        print(mult)
        cont = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ")
   elif op1 == '**':
        car = (x ** num)
        print(car)
        cont = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ")


   else:
        print("error")
        pass
    
else:
       print("Finished")
```

Basically, it work's when adding num1 and num2, it works again one more time since it uses x and the new number(num) along with a new operator. However, the problem occurs when continuing AGAIN, as the program uses x instead of the new number(y/z/div/mult/car).

Sorry if this is phrased bad(I'm new), but basically I want it to use the new variable after selecting continue twice, but I don't know how to.

Comment: create a variable outside the loop that keeps track of the last result

Comment: Have you tried saving the result of each operation back into `x`? Something like `x  = x * num` calculates the product using the old `x` and then saves the result in `x`

Comment: why dont you store the new result back into X? why are you storing it into different variable names for different operations?

Comment: Also you should consider the DRY principle. Any time you see yourself writting the same code again and again, there is probably a better way to write it.

Comment: @MirrorMaster Have any of the answers answered your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-use the same variable. Instead of writing y/z/div/mult/car = ..., you can replace all of the with x = ....

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list to store data

```
some_data = 5
some string = "hello"
my_list = [] # create empty list that can store any data type (int, str, float...)

my_list.append(some_data) # my_list = [5]
my_list.append(some_string) # my list = [5, "hello"]

# to access the element within the list you can use the subscript operator '[]'
# for example my_list[0] returns 5, my list[1] returns "hello"
# my_list[:] returns the entire list
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the last answer to always be x, that way it can work every time you repeat it. For example:

```py
while cont == "Y":
   op1 = input("Select operation: (+, -, /, *, **)")
   num = float(input(("Input the next number: ")))
   if op1 == '+':
        x += num  # Re-assign to x
        print (x)
        cont = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ")
   elif op1 == '-':
        x -= num  # re-assign to x
        print (x)
        cont = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ")
   elif op1 == '/':
        x /= num  # Re-assign x
        print (x)
        cont = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ")
   elif op1 == '*':
        x += num  # Re-assign x
        print (x)
        cont = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ")
   elif op1 == '**':
        x **= num  # Re-assign x
        print (x)
        cont = input("Would you like to continue? (Y/N): ")


   else:
        print("error")
        pass
    
else:
       print("Finished")
```

Now this program can work forever as the last answer is always reassigned to x.

If you are unsure of the lines of code I used to perform the operations, for example:

```py
x += num  # Same as x = x + num

x **= num  # Same as x = x**num
```

It just makes your code a little cleaner.

CONCLUSION: By having the variable 'x' always be assigned the to the answer of the previous calculation we can infinitely repeat operations on it as it is always being stored, then reassigned to adapt to the next iteration of the program.